# Selenium Webdriver: Select radiobutton with specific span title in list

Tags: c#, dom, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have the following HTML with in this case 2 items in my ul. Now I want to check (click) the radiobutton where `<span title = "SeleniumUpload">`. In this HTML there is only one element, but it can be many more.

How do I find this element?

HTML example:

```
<ul id="ctl00_cpm_AlbumMain_thumbs" class="listAlbums clearfix nospace-bottom" mediastorepartnertype="extrafilm" style="height: 160px;">
<li id="ctl00_cpm_AlbumMain_1da02a93-76cd-46a5-8dfb-e841aedf4398|2ab03151-7f88-4924-9471-248786ba46c0_handle" class="folderitemhandle" pagenr="1">
    <a title="Bekijk de foto's in dit album." href="/nl/myaccount/myphotos/album.aspx?albumid=2ab03151-7f88-4924-9471-248786ba46c0">
    <img id="ctl00_cpm_AlbumMain_1da02a93-76cd-46a5-8dfb-e841aedf4398|2ab03151-7f88-4924-9471-248786ba46c0_handle_image" class="lazy" width="100" data-original="http://photos.myserver.com.stage/photos/nastemp1/volume1/8889361a-c9e5-4cbd-a5a3-bbf7612dd370/131016/4/8/48f1d74f-0e62-455a-ba60-2a64fc3ff2a6.thumb.jpg?upd=635175161317600000" alt="Bekijk de foto's in dit album." src="http://photos.myserver.com.stage/photos/nastemp1/volume1/8889361a-c9e5-4cbd-a5a3-bbf7612dd370/131016/4/8/48f1d74f-0e62-455a-ba60-2a64fc3ff2a6.thumb.jpg?upd=635175161317600000" style="display: inline;">
    </a>
    <label class="albumTitle">
        <input id="ctl00_cpm_AlbumMain_1da02a93-76cd-46a5-8dfb-e841aedf4398|2ab03151-7f88-4924-9471-248786ba46c0_handle_box" type="radio" onclick="javascript:SelectFolder('ctl00_cpm_AlbumMain_1da02a93-76cd-46a5-8dfb-e841aedf4398|2ab03151-7f88-4924-9471-248786ba46c0_handle','1da02a93-76cd-46a5-8dfb-e841aedf4398|2ab03151-7f88-4924-9471-248786ba46c0');" name="ctl00$cpm$AlbumMain$1da02a93-76cd-46a5-8dfb-e841aedf4398|2ab03151-7f88-4924-9471-248786ba46c0_handle$" value="box">
        <span title="Test (2)">Test (2)</span>
    </label>
</li>
<li id="ctl00_cpm_AlbumMain_1da02a93-76cd-46a5-8dfb-e841aedf4398|35b9a18d-6203-4fcb-a05f-decb8672d1c7_handle" class="folderitemhandle" pagenr="1">
    <a title="Bekijk de foto's in dit album." href="/nl/myaccount/myphotos/album.aspx?albumid=35b9a18d-6203-4fcb-a05f-decb8672d1c7">
    <img id="ctl00_cpm_AlbumMain_1da02a93-76cd-46a5-8dfb-e841aedf4398|35b9a18d-6203-4fcb-a05f-decb8672d1c7_handle_image" class="lazy" width="100" data-original="http://photos.myserver.com.stage/photos/nastemp1/volume1/8889361a-c9e5-4cbd-a5a3-bbf7612dd370/131016/7/f/7f2efe77-7754-463e-8eb7-f2853cfa0f07.thumb.jpg?upd=635175162493870000" alt="Bekijk de foto's in dit album." src="http://photos.myserver.com.stage/photos/nastemp1/volume1/8889361a-c9e5-4cbd-a5a3-bbf7612dd370/131016/7/f/7f2efe77-7754-463e-8eb7-f2853cfa0f07.thumb.jpg?upd=635175162493870000" style="display: inline;">
    </a>
    <label class="albumTitle">
        <input id="ctl00_cpm_AlbumMain_1da02a93-76cd-46a5-8dfb-e841aedf4398|35b9a18d-6203-4fcb-a05f-decb8672d1c7_handle_box" type="radio" onclick="javascript:SelectFolder('ctl00_cpm_AlbumMain_1da02a93-76cd-46a5-8dfb-e841aedf4398|35b9a18d-6203-4fcb-a05f-decb8672d1c7_handle','1da02a93-76cd-46a5-8dfb-e841aedf4398|35b9a18d-6203-4fcb-a05f-decb8672d1c7');" name="ctl00$cpm$AlbumMain$1da02a93-76cd-46a5-8dfb-e841aedf4398|35b9a18d-6203-4fcb-a05f-decb8672d1c7_handle$" value="box">
        <span title="SeleniumUpload (3)">Selenium... (3)</span>
    </label>
</li>
```

This I have so far, but the title attribute of the span returns an empty string. Why is this?

```
var albums = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("albumTitle")); 
Console.WriteLine("Found {0} photo-albums", albums.Count);
foreach (var we in albums)
{
var span = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("span"));
String title = span.GetAttribute("title"); // returns empty string, I need this title value
Console.WriteLine("we.text:'{0}' title:''{1}",we.Text, title);

// work around
if (we.Text.Contains("Seleni")) // I should be able to check on span title
{
  var input = we.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[id*='ctl00_cpm_AlbumMain_']"));
  var id = input.GetAttribute("id");
  Console.WriteLine(we.Text + " Id:" + id);
}
}
```

Comment: Simplifying your HTML would help a lot.

Comment: I have nothing to do with the HTML so I can't change anything to it.

Comment: I just meant simplifying it in the context of the question. Creating simplified scenarios makes it easier for readers to assess your question.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to use an `xpath` selector. Something like `//*/span[title="SeleniumUpload"]` if you want to match that exact title. If you want to just match something close to it, then you'll need to investigate using `xpath` with `contains`.

Comment: Ok, but then I still don't have the Id of the input button which is in the same label. See <label class="albumTitle">.

Comment: Right. Sorry. To get to that you'll have to dig even deeper into the magic of `xpath` and `DOM`. First you're going to have to find the parent node of the element you just found, then you're going to need to find the `input` node that is the child of that aforementioned parent.

Comment: I would give you code and some examples, but I don't know `C#`.

Comment: Some code would be usefull. Doesn't matter what, I'll change it to C#. it would be great to just have an idea how to do it. It's the first time I use Selenium. Thx for the help!

Comment: Added my code to the topic. I find all elements by classname "albumTitle". This label contains the input and span elements. However I get an empty string on the span title attribute.